# Given key was not found in dictionary Visual C++ when grabbing data from MySQL

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, visual-c++-2012

I'm currently working on a RFID project, and what I'm trying to do is to grab the value from MySQL local database that I had created. However, whenever I try doing so, it returns an exception that "Given key was not found in dictionary".

Inserted below is the code:

```
try 
{
    int identification = Int32::Parse(NUM->Text);
    String^ constr = "Server=127.0.0.1; Uid=root;Pwd=588588;Database=nationalid;CharSet=utf8;";
    MySqlConnection^ con = gcnew MySqlConnection(constr);
    MySqlCommand^  cmd = gcnew MySqlCommand("select * from userinfo WHERE identification=" + identification + "", con);
    con->Open();
    MySqlDataReader^ dr = cmd->ExecuteReader();
    while (dr->Read())
    {
        FN->Text = dr->GetString(1);
        MN->Text = dr->GetString(2);
        LN->Text = dr->GetString(3);
        N->Text = dr->GetString(4);
        B->Text = dr->GetString(5);
        A->Text = dr->GetString(6);
        TIN2->Text = dr->GetString(7);
    }
    con->Close();
}
catch (Exception^ ex)
{
    MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
}
```

Comment: Assuming that exceeption is coming from your `dr-GetString()` function calls, first thing I'd think to check is the DataReader works with a 0 based index, . And you're starting with 1, do you actually have 8 columns in your result set? Otherwise, have you debugged the code to see which line it's failing on?

Comment: Just looking at the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader_GetString.htm), you can use the column name from your database to get the value from your result set, which might solve your problem, provided that's where the error is happening, as well as make your code more readable.

Comment: I tried removing those and left only the mySql command, but it still returned the error

Comment: Please try provide a little more information, the error could be happening on any one of those lines of code, but guessing won't get us anywhere. Does the error tell you what line the error is occurring on? Have you tried using the debugger?